# Jasmine Testing with vm in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Trying to test a simple test in Jasmine & Karma and AngularJs frameWork,
controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('bsp.account')
    .controller('Account', Account);

/* @ngInject */
function Account(userService, accountService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'Accounts';
    vm.username = userService.getUsername();

    vm.showPasswordModal = accountService.showPasswordModal;
    vm.showLogoutModal = accountService.showLogoutModal;

    activate();
    ////////////////
    function activate() {

    }
}
})();
```

Can anyOne tell me how do i write a simple test case using Jasmin with this code ? and also maybe a possible methode and its test,
My test code below:

```
describe('Account', function() {

var scope,
    controller;

beforeEach(module('bsp.account'));
//sample testCase--
it('testCheck', function() {
    expect('helloWorld').toBe("helloWorld");
});

describe('Account', function() {
    //injecting the scope&controller--
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('Account', {
            $scope: scope
        });
        scope.vm = controller;

    }));

});
it("checkTitle",function(){
var vm = controller("Account",{$scope:scope});
expect(vm.title).toEqual("Accounts"); 
}); 
});
```

karma ,response:

```
Running "karma:unit:run" (karma) task
[2015-10-23 15:11:03.542] [DEBUG] config - Loading config   /vagrant/frontend/build/karma-unit.js
    ✗ checkTitle
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'controller("Account",{$scope:scope})')
    at /vagrant/frontend/src/app/account/account.controller.spec.js:33

LOG LOG: undefined
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) LOG: undefined
LOG LOG: '** if *********'
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) LOG: '** if *********'

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 37 of 37 (1 FAILED) (0.134 secs / 0.128 secs)

Warning: Task "karma:unit:run" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Aborted due to warnings.
Completed in 10.849s at Fri Oct 23 2015 15:11:04 GMT-0700 (PDT) - Waiting...
Any suggestions is appreciated,Am new to Jasmin testing.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually instantiating a `BoardPerformance` controller in your `beforeEach` block but the code you are showing is for `Account`, so I understand that's a mistake.

So for your simple test case to run try this:

```
describe('Account', function() {

  var scope, controller, userServiceMock;

  beforeEach(module('bsp'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    userServiceMock = {
      getUsername: function(){} 
    }
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('Account', {
      'userService': userServiceMock
    });
  }));

  it('checkTitle', function(){
    expect(controller.title).toEqual('Accounts'); 
  });

});
```

Comment: My sincere apologies,am just lost between writing a lot of test cases of different controller,i have updated it    .gives me an error,    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'controller.title')

Comment: Does the `bsp` module include the `bsp.account` as a dependency?

Comment: yes ,it does have it.updated,it ,but even after including it ,gives me error     ✗ checkTitle
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userServiceProvider <- userService <- Account
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=userServiceProvider%20%3C-%20userService%20%3C-%20Account
     at /vagrant/frontend/vendor/angular/angular.js:4031
     at getService (/vagrant/frontend/vendor/angular/angular.js:4178)
     at /vagrant/frontend/vendor/angular/angular.js:4036

 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'controller.title')
     at

Comment: please let me update my question in some time,i realize there is a something to do with dependency Injection,let me get those pieces in place and get back,  @Pablo Viloslada ,i appreciate your help ,let me update and i would look forward to your suggestions.Thank You

Comment: You can either mock that `userService` or include in your test the module that loads the service.

Comment: @ Pablo ,I have answered with your updated test scripts ,but getting some errors, i just want to test the title ,but the karma is now pointing at different resource and throwing error!!

Comment: It would be better if you just edit the question instead of posting a new answer. The problem now is the way you are tying to mock your service so I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: ,thanks it worked,(you are AWSOME!!!),and also can you share some thoughts about the vm when used in controller ,how does it matter if i have to use controller ? and am just curious using the controller directly ,is this the best practice ?

Comment: Using the "controller as" syntax you remove the need of injecting `$scope` to your controllers. Then everything what you attach to the `var vm = this` will be exposed to the view. So in a test when you instantiate your controller with `$controller` you get an object with all the exposed properties and methods. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the new test case in Jasmin,

```
describe('Account', function() { 
  var scope, controller, userServiceMock,accountServiceMock; 
  beforeEach(module('bsp')); 
  beforeEach(function() {
    userServiceMock = {
       getUsername: function(){} //this is a method inside userService
    };
    accountServiceMock = {
      showPasswordModal :function(){}//this is a method inside accountService
    };
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
scope = $rootScope.$new();
controller = $controller('Account', {
  'userService': userServiceMock,
  'accountService':accountServiceMock
});
  }));

 describe('testing Title',function(){
   it('checkTitle', function(){
   expect(controller.title).toEqual('Accounts'); 
   });  
 }); 
});
```

It is very basic but has necessary information for controllers with dependency and also the vm..thank to Pablo